# etale cohomology of ${\mathbb P}^n_k$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Suppose $k$ is a number field. I want to compute $H^\ast({\mathbb P}^n_k,\mu_l^{\otimes r})$ where $l,r\in {\mathbb N}$. I know that Milne has some computations, but he assumes throughout that his field is ${\mathbb C}$. I want to know if it differs when $k$ is number field.

Disclaimer: This is not a homework problem. However, I am just a starter when it comes to the etale world. Any hints/comments will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The projective bundle formula gives that $H^{i}(\mathbf{P}^n,\mu^{\otimes r}_l)=\bigoplus_{0\leq k\leq n} H^{i-2k}(k,\mu^{\otimes r-k}_l)$ (note that $\mu^{\otimes r}_l$ makes sense for $r\in\mathbf Z$).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get $H^\ast({\mathbb P}^\infty_k)$ from $H^\ast({\mathbb P}^n_k)$, where $k$ is still a number field?

Comment: @ Denis-Charles: How would you prove projective bundle formula for etale cohomology (over number field)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G:=\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$. There is a Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence
$$E^{pq}_2=H^p(G, H^q(\mathbb{P}^n_{\bar{k}}\,,\mu _l^{\otimes r})\ \Rightarrow\ H^*(\mathbb{P}^n_{k}\,,\mu _l^{\otimes r})\ .$$
The cohomology of $\mathbb{P}^n_{\bar{k}}$ is well known, but the Galois cohomology is rather difficult to control, already for $H^1$ -- this is essentially class field theory.